# Memory issue in xamarin Forms lists

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have make a simple project to investigate on a performance issue in my Xamarin.Forms application.

I have two nested list for a classic master-detail structure. Accord to the MVVM pattern, I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for ViewModel classes and use ObservableCollection for lists.
In the main view I have two standard ListView, the first (masters) binded to the master collection, che second (details) binded to the details collection of the selected item of the master list. Both have CachingStrategy="RecycleElement".

When run UWP application, in Diagnostic Tools of Visual Studio can be see memory usage of application.
When an element of the masters list is selected, the details list is rendered and the used memory grow up, when masters list selected item change, the details list is redrowed with the respective items and used memory grow up, also if there is less items to display, if previous masters item is selected again, used memory grow up again. Every time that masters list selected items change and the details list is refreshed, used memory grow up without ever decreasing. Seems that objects used for render the details list items never be collected by GC.

I think it's too evident effect to be a bug no one has ever noticed, but the test project is very minimal, all viewmodels inherits from MvvmLight ViewModelBase class, all properties use Set method and all list properties type is ObservableCollection, the only custom code is for initial load.
I think that I make a mistake that I can't see.

Below viewmodels and view code

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Load();
    }

    private RelayCommand _reloadCommand;
    public RelayCommand ReloadCommand { get { return _reloadCommand ?? (_reloadCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Load)); } }

    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } set { this.Set(ref _items, value); } }

    private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { get { return _selectedItem; } set { this.Set(ref _selectedItem, value); } }

    private SubitemViewModel _selectedSubitem;
    public SubitemViewModel SelectedSubitem { get { return _selectedSubitem; } set { this.Set(ref _selectedSubitem, value); } }

    private void Load()
    {
        int[] ranges = { 15, 10, 5, 20 };

        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(
            from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 15)
            select new ItemViewModel()
            {
                Label = $"Item {i}",
                Items = new ObservableCollection<SubitemViewModel>(from s in Enumerable.Range(1, ranges[i % 4] )
                        select new SubitemViewModel() { Label = $"Subitem {i}.{s}" })
            });
    }
}
```

ItemViewModel.cs

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _label;
    public string Label { get { return _label; } set { this.Set(ref _label, value); } }

    private ObservableCollection<SubitemViewModel> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<SubitemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } set { this.Set(ref _items, value); } }
}
```

SubItemViewModel.cs

```
public class SubitemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _label;
    public string Label { get { return _label; } set { this.Set(ref _label, value); } }
}
```

MainView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModel"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Masters" />
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Details" />

            <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ItemViewModel">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Items}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubitem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:SubitemViewModel">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The complete test project can be download here: [MemoryTest.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap6zAueW9pU-5tsWvHwJjlLO57RrQw?e=uoQ8tj)

Comment: Is this actually a problem? Can you show some actual numbers? If memory usage goes up by a few KB per time, the GC just doesn't want to kick in. This is not a memory leak anyway, it's managed code.

Comment: Start 51Mb
Item1-> 10 Subitems 53Mb
Item2-> 5 Subitems 53Mb
Item3-> 20 Subitems 56Mb
Item4->15 Subitems 58Mb
Item3->20 Subitems 60Mb
Every item Item3 is selected, used memory grow up of 2Mb

Comment: As @CodeCaster , first try to enforce garbage collection and see what happens. If there is memory leakage you are using some MVVM plugin and it may be that it is leaking. Try using just Xamarin's built-in MVVM.

Comment: Probably memory leak is not the best term, but memory usage grow up without never grow down. This means that some objects that which I expect will no longer be used, remain used and can't be deallocated by GC.
I have try to force GC.Collect in the SelectedItem set, Performance Tools show GC event, but memory usage not change.
I doubt that a very used librory as MvvmLight, have such a bug, but I have try implementing directly INotifyPropertyChanged... Same behaviour.

Comment: @MrWolf Hi, here is a discussion about Xamarin Forms memory management: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23097/xamarin-forms-memory-management